# Trying to convert an array full of 1s and 0s (binary) to string and then to int in Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, binary

```
int[] configurationArray = new int[8];
        
int configurationIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if(vertexState[i]+cube[i] == 1)
    {
        configurationArray[i] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        configurationArray[i] = 0;
    }
}

string binaryString = configurationArray.ToString();
configurationIndex = Convert.ToInt32(binaryString, 2);
Debug.Log(configurationIndex);


return configurationIndex;
```

this error appears:

> ```
> FormatException: Could not find any parsable digits.
> System.ParseNumbers.StringToInt (System.String value, System.Int32 fromBase, System.Int32 flags, System.Int32* parsePos) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.ParseNumbers.StringToInt (System.String value, System.Int32 fromBase, System.Int32 flags) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Convert.ToInt32 (System.String value, System.Int32 fromBase) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> ```

Comment: `string binaryString = string.Join("", configurationArray);` ?

Comment: int arrays don't have an inherit ToString method, so your binaryString just contains "System.Int32[]". You could try this to get your String `String.Join("", configurationArray.Reverse().Select(i => i.ToString()))`. If you don't need them in reverse order, just go with what @Ruzihm wrote.

Comment: This is an ideal opportunity to [learn how to debug](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to replace your `configurationArray.ToString()` with `string.Concat(configurationArray);` when setting `binaryString` variable.

The output of `.ToString()` on the array is `System.Int32[]`, which is why you are getting an error on the conversation to int.